# onbehalfof organisation sign up problem

Tags: civimember

We have a problem that may have started after upgrading from 4.4.11 to 4.4.19 on Drupal - anyway, it's started happening fairly recently.

We have public page that allows for a membership contribution for an individual to register/sign up and create an organisation at the same time (Employer of). Normally there's a contribution in the Organisation and a membership record in the organisation - and a membership by relationship for the individual.

The problem is that the individual membership record is not being created now. (It can be fixed up by admin to create the relevant record).

I've been tracing the code and I think it is a relationship permission problem.  If I remove a permission check in CRM_Contact_BAO_Relationship::getRelationship() then the right record is created. However this doesn't seem like a good fix for the problem.

Can anyone think of a change to permissions or onbehalfof around this time which might have this effect.

We do have some custom code in this area - which adds permission is_permission_b_a in CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm::processOnBehalfOrganization() - I think I've tried removing that .

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar issue reported in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17067 where inherited membership(s) not created due to permission check in getRelationship(). I have submitted the PR in the ticket itself and the reason why the PR is still not merged is because there are some ACL changes going in 4.6.9 and that will fix the remaining issues reported by Dave Jenkin in his last comment.

Comment: Thanks Monish. Your first fix was where I'd identified the problem. Putting in your fixes sorted it for us.

Comment: Can I ask that this fix be fitted to 4.4LTS pls? Should I add to the JIRA report?

Comment: Eileen is the right person to ask if we can include the changes in 4.4LTS and/or you can ask in the Jira ticket itself - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17067

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no custom code that explicitly creates the membership on the individual, your individual's membership is inherited from the organization's membership by the settings on the organization's membership type.

**A change in membership type** granted on the form from one that has inheritance by relationship to one that doesn't could be the culprit.

Likewise, **limiting the number of contacts who can inherit** the membership, also set on the membership type, could result in this.  If you have a limit, CiviCRM may not automatically grant the membership.

The permissions on the relationship *should* not make a difference.  The paradigm is a trade association: one employee should be allowed to manage the organization record and the other employees, but all of the employees should have the benefits of membership.  Membership inheritance is not affected by the permissioning on a relationship in stock CiviCRM.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The membership type hasn't changed in ages. The problem and fix Monish identified fixed the problem.